# django model name in save() method

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

I want to get the name of the model inside the save() method . I want to correct this line

```
self.slug = create_slug(self.model_object, self.slug)
```

here I need to get the model name `self.model_name`. here `model course` inherited `basemodel` but I need to get the `model` name as `course`. How can I do that? Somebody please help me.

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=500)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self._state.adding == True:
            if not self.slug:
                self.slug = create_slug(self.model_object, self.slug)

        return super(BaseModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Course(BaseModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "course"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `__class__` magic property

```
self.slug = create_slug(self.__class__, self.slug)
```

Comment: 'str' object has no attribute 'objects' . i got this error . It taking that model as a string.

Comment: @tstudent I don't see any mention of `objects` in code you pasted. So I couldn't account for it. Update your question or create another one.

Comment: instead of self.__class__.__name__. i tried self.__class__ and its worked. thanks ..